# Appearance of built-in Community Follow Button component

Tags: css, lightning-community

When I add the built-in Follow component to a Community page, I am able to customize its appearance.  For example, I can configure it to display with curved edges (see image).  However, when someone clicks the button to follow the record, the customized button formatting disappears.  This is a poor user experience.  I am hoping to resolve this without writing a custom follow component.  Thoughts?[image: Community Follow Button]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely because a css class is added when it is selected, to indicate that is has been clicked.

I would suggest you debug the button for when this change happen, verify the added css class and modify your css scoping so your user experience remains the same before and after clicking.

Comment: Since I am using the SF follow component, how would I modify the CSS for it?

Comment: I just updated the question with the CSS I am seeing.  Pls. let me know how you suggest I change it.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got the Follow/Unfollow buttons to have the proper border-radius by overriding the CSS in the template with the following code.  It seems to be a bug in the Salesforce Follow button component that lets you style the button but the border-radius property doesn't hold true when the button is in the Unfollow state.

[image]

Comment: its not a bug - and using !important is a bad practice. you should either scope the css properly or create your own custom button. since it seems you are using a standard salesforce button, if there is a change in the calsses following a release, your styling will break.

Comment: Pls. help me understand why it isn't a bug?  The Salesforce Follow component lets you set the style of the button.  It looks good when the button shows to an unfollower.  However, the format changes when the Follow button is pressed.  3/4 of the styling holds, but the border-radious on the right does not.  This seems like a bug to me.  Changing 3/4 of the defined formatting when the button is clicked looks bad.